# Angular scrollPositionRestoration works reverse

Tags: angular

I added **scrollPositionRestoration : enabled** in my app.routing module.ts.
Then i tried to route from one route to another route using routerLink in an anchor tag.

**mycomponent.ts**

```
<a routerLink="/route1"></a>
```

In my component.ts while navigating to some other route it reaches to the top of the page.But when i am switching **scrollPositionRestoration : disabled** ,it retains the scroll position of the current route to the navigating route.

Shortly,

**scrollPositionRestoration : disabled** => new route scrolls to previous scroll position

**scrollPositionRestoration : enabled** => new route scrolls to Top

Is this the actual behaviour or something is going wrong in my app.

Comment: scrollPositionRestoration  has several issues [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration), `scrollPositionRestoration` controls what happens when you *navigate back*. So, `scrollPositionRestoration: enabled` means that *when you navigate back* to the previous route, it restores the position. I think `anchorScrolling` or `scrollOffset` are closer to your goal.